# How to correctly specify artithmetic expression in TextView for recognition by TalkBack

Tags: java, android, html, kotlin

For a fitness app, I'm looking to display a message on a smartwatch emulator which can be read by the TalkBack facility and (when spoken) is understandable by the user when TalkBack highlights the TextView. The `+` sign has several different meanings, e.g. plus, add, positive, increase, etc. In this case I want the word 'plus' to be spoken by TalkBack. Is this something that Java can provide? This also needs to be something understandable by different languages when strings are localised.

**Expected result**

Text on display: `Number of steps: 4↑ (2↑ + 2↑)`

Talkback should say: "4 up (2 up + 2 up)"

**Current code**

```
    val imageGetter = Html.ImageGetter { name ->
        val resId = if (name == "arrow") { R.drawable.ic_arrow_up }
        else { throw IllegalArgumentException("what the heck is $arrow") }

        ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(resources, resId, requireActivity().theme)?.apply {
            setBounds(0, 0, intrinsicWidth, intrinsicHeight)
        }
    }

    val txtNumberOfSteps = getString(R.string.number_of_steps)
    val txt4 = String.format("%d", 4) 
    val txt2 = String.format("%d", 2) 
    val htmlTxtSteps = "$txtNumberOfSteps $txt4 <img src=\"arrow\"/> ($txt2 <img src=\"arrow\"/> + $txt2" <img src=\"arrow\"/>)"
    val txtStepsClimbed = Html.fromHtml(htmlTxtSteps, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT, imageGetter, null)

    myTv.setText = txtStepsClimbed
```

**strings.xml**

```
<string name="number_of_steps">Number of steps: </string>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try updating the `contentDescription` of the TextView every time the values change.

For example, for

> Text on display: `Number of steps: 4↑ (2↑ + 2↑)`

you could call

```
myTv.contentDescription = "Four up times two up plus two up"
```

I might've misrepresented the parenthesis but you get the gist.  Simply, set a String that says exactly what you want the TalkBack feature to read back to you.

Hoping this helps!

Comment: @Swarthy46 What do you mean by different amounts of steps? The point I'm trying to make is that TalkBack will read whatever you write as the `contentDescription` of any `View` object, which you can then set and reset to your specific needs.